# Why is softmax linear on a semi-logarithmic scale?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently, I came across the following statement which I struggle to make sense of:

> the softmax function is not a linear transformation, however, it exhibits a linear behavior on a semi-logarithmic scale.

Indeed, if I compute the softmax for a vector $\mathbf{z} = (-3, -1, 2, 3, 10)$ and then plot the result on a semi-log scale I get a straight line:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

def softmax(z: npt.NDArray) -> npt.NDArray:
    vec_exp = np.exp(z)
    vec_sum = np.sum(vec_exp)
    
    return vec_exp / vec_sum

# compute softmax for array z
z = np.array([-3, -1, 2, 3, 10])
out = softmax(z)

# result
# [2.25747076e-06 1.66805781e-05 3.35038367e-04 9.10728704e-04 9.98735295e-01]
```

[here the resulting semi-log plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh23l.png)

What I don't understand is why this is the case. After all, as far as I can tell, the logarithm of the softmax is not a liner expression, is it?

$$
\begin{align}
&\sigma(\mathbf{z})_i = \frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{z_j}} \\
&\ln(\sigma(\mathbf{z})_i) = \ln(e^{z_i}) - \ln(\sum_{j=1}^K e^{z_j}) \\
&\ln(\sigma(\mathbf{z})_i) = z_i - \ln(\sum_{j=1}^K e^{z_j})
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Because the sum is constant.